# Is there a way to get the name of web application without using Servlet features?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using Tomcat as the application server, and have 4 web applications running on it. Due to some common requirements across the web applications, I have developed a library which is put in Tomcat's `lib` folder for sharing the implementation to the web applications. However, I want to implement some resource management features on the library, such as to create and manage singleton resources to each of the web applications (that is, one web application gets one singleton resource). What I suppose to do so is to manage a `ConcurrentHashMap` and stores each of the singleton resources in it. However, when a web application calls the library for accessing its resource, I need to get the name of the web application which the caller belongs to so I can return the right resource to the caller. Is there a good way to implement things like this (ways that the application don't need to pass parameters or identifications while calling the library to get resource is preferred)? Or it's just a wrong way to think like this, and there is a better solution?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, what you describe is not a *java singleton* pattern, since you want one object per web application. In fact, I think you need one of those objects per `ServletContext`. I cannot understand why you do not want to use Servlet features, because the right way to do that is to use a ServletContextListener in each web app (it can be the same class) that creates your *singleton resources* (can also be common classes) and put them as attributes in the ServletContext (exactly one per web application).

The ServletContext attributes are then easy to use from any servlet (`request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("attribute_name")` or jsp (`<jsp:useBean id="attribute_name" scope="application" type="..."/>` and then `${attribute_name}`)